# Why doesn't "select_for_update()" work in Django with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, select-for-update

I have a table like below:

```
SELECT id, name FROM node;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  5 | na   |
+----+------+
```

Then define below function:

```
>>> def foo_with_sfu(seconds):
...     with transaction.atomic():
...         node = Node.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=5)
...         time.sleep(seconds)
...         node = Node.objects.get(pk=5)
...         print(node.name)
...
```

I was hoping the select_for_update will lock row  pk=5 so if I open another console to change the node.name during time.sleep, the change operation will be blocked.

But actually  when  I run the function, and run update sql in another console  during the time.sleep, the update were not blocked.

It seems the select for update not locking up the row. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `select_for_update()` query is never evaluated, so the lock is never executed on the database. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) for when and how querysets get evaluated.

If you simply wrap the call in a queryset-evaluating function your test should work. For example:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    node = list(Node.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=5))
```

Answer (score -1):

To run `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, you need to put `print(node)` after [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) as shown below. *You can also put `bool(node)`, `len(node)` or `list(node)` instead of `print(node)`:

```py
node = Node.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=5)
print(node) # bool(node), len(node) or list(node) is also fine
```

You can see [**my question and answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842206/are-there-any-other-cases-which-select-for-update-doesnt-work-but-works-wit) explaining more about `select_for_update()` in Django: