# Are there any other cases which "select_for_update()" doesn't work but works with "print(qs)" in Django?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django, select-for-update

I have **`Person` model** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

### <**CASE 1**>

Then, when I use [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) and [**update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) of [**a queryset**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) together as shown below (I use **Django 3.2.16**):

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                        # Here              # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().update(name="Tom"))
                        # Here                    # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().all().update(name="Tom"))
                        # Here                           # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).update(name="Tom"))
                                                  
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Only **`UPDATE` query** is run without **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** as shown below. *I use **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the queries of PostgreSQL** and you can check [**on PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

But, when I use `select_for_update()` and `update()` of **a queryset** separately then put `print(qs)` between them as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                       
    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update()
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.update(name="Tom")

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().all()
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.update(name="Tom")

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1)
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.update(name="Tom")
                                                  
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

In addition, when I use `select_for_update()` and [**save()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) of **an object** separately as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                            # Here
    person1 = Person.objects.select_for_update().first()
    person1.name = "Tom"
    person1.save() # Here
                            # Here
    person2 = Person.objects.select_for_update().all().first()
    person2.name = "Tom"
    person2.save() # Here
                            # Here
    person3 = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).first()
    person3.name = "Tom"
    person3.save() # Here
                            # Here
    person4 = Person.objects.select_for_update().get(id=1)
    person4.name = "Tom"
    person4.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

### <**CASE 2**>

And, when I use `select_for_update()` and [**delete()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete) of **a queryset** together as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                        # Here              # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().delete())
                        # Here                    # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().all().delete())
                        # Here                           # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).delete())

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Only **`DELETE` query** is run without **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** as shown below.

[image]

But, when I use `select_for_update()` and `delete()` of **a queryset** separately then put `print(qs)` between them as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update()
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.delete()

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().all()
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.delete()

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1)
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.delete()
                                                  
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

In addition, when I use `select_for_update()` and `delete()` of **an object** together as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                        # Here              # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().first().delete())

    # Or
                        # Here                            # Here    
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().all().first().delete())
    
    # Or
                        # Here                                   # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).first().delete())

    # Or
                        # Here                        # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().get(id=1).delete())

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know [**QuerySets are lazy**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) and [**When QuerySets are evaluated**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

So, are there any other cases which `select_for_update()` doesn't work but works with `print(qs)` in Django in addition to what I've shown above?

Comment: That's the behaviour I would expect, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is only relevant when you are actually selecting rows, not sure these are examples of it not working

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is other case which `select_for_update()` doesn't work but works with `print(qs)` in Django.

For example, when I use `select_for_update()` and [**count()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#count) of **a queryset** together as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
                        # Here              # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().count())
                        # Here                    # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().all().count())
                        # Here                           # Here
    print(Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).count())

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT` query** is run instead of **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** as shown below:

[image]

But, when I use `select_for_update()` and `count()` of **a queryset** separately then put `print(qs)` between them as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update()
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.count()

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().all()
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.count()

    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1)
    print(qs) # Here
    qs.count()

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `SELECT` queries** are run as shown below but there are **two queries `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `SELECT`** instead of **one single query `SELECT FOR UPDATE`**:

[image]

So to run **one single query `SELECT FOR UPDATE`** with the same result, I use `select_for_update()` and [**len()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) together which is a built-in function in Python as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
        # Here              # Here
    print(len(Person.objects.select_for_update()))
        # Here              # Here
    print(len(Person.objects.select_for_update().all()))
        # Here              # Here
    print(len(Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1)))

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, **one single query `SELECT FOR UPDATE`** is run as shown below:

[image]